# lower triangular matrix give wrong answer when 0

Tags: c, matrix, gaussian

I've been working on this code for get the lower triangular matrix for solving linear equations, here's the code:

```
int jordan (){
    float fracc=0;
    int z=0;
    fila=0;
    colum=0;
    for(colum=0;colum<cant;colum++) {
          buscar_ceros(); /*here we call*/
         for(fila=colum+1;fila<cant;fila++) {
            if(a[fila][colum]!=0) {
                fracc=(-((a[fila][colum])/(a[colum][colum])));
                for(z=0;z<=cant;z++) {
                    a[fila][z]=a[fila][z]+(fracc*a[colum][z]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    impri();
    return 0;
}
```

It works when I input a matrix when the first element isn't `0` something like this:

input

```
0 2 5 6
1 0 -2 4
2 4 0 -2
```

output

```
0 2 5 6
-1.$ -1.$ -1.$ -1.$
1.$ 1.$ 1.$ 1.$
```

I think a possible solution it's write an algorithm to sort the rows but it could be another way.

Here's the code I made to avoid the 0's:

```
int buscar_ceros(){
int m=0,r;
x=0;
flag=0;
    do{
        if((a[x][colum])!=0){
            flag=1;
    }
    x++;
}while(!(flag==1));

flag=0;
    for(r=0;r<=cant;r++){
        m=a[x][r];
        a[x][r]=a[fila][r];
        a[fila][r]=m;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You check `a[fila][colum]` for zero but divide by `a[colum][colum]`.

Comment: yes I didn't see that so, it'll be better if the matrix if sorted by rows and put the 0 row in other position?

Comment: fracc=(-((a[fila][colum])/(a[colum][colum]))); causes division by 0 in the first loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if at any iteration of your outer loop `a[colum][colum]` is exactly `0.0` then dividing by that value produces infinite results and / or a floating-point exception.  That can most easily be triggered when `a[0][0]` is zero, but it can also happen later, when processing other columns.

You also have a potential numeric stability issue when `a[colum][colum]` is very close to zero at any iteration.

You need to be prepared to recognize such cases because they are unavoidable for singular matrices.  For other matrices, you need to be prepared to exchange rows to avoid it.

In particular, at each iteration of the outer loop, you can scan the remaining rows for the one with the largest absolute value in the target column, and swap rows if necessary to make that one the current row.

Comment: @user2461687, note too that for a linear equation solver, if you swap rows of the coefficient matrix then you need to be sure to perform a corresponding swap in the right-hand side vector.

Comment: I using only one bidimensional array :/

Comment: A system of linear equations has the form: MX = V, where M is the coefficient matrix and V is the right-hand side (and X is the n-dimensional variable).  I'm just saying that when you swap rows in M, you need a corresponding swap in V.  If V is the zero vector (or any other vector for which all components are equal) then you have no issue.  If you're using an augmented matrix of the form (M | V) (i.e. one more column than there are rows) then you get the result for free, as long as you're careful.  Otherwise, it requires attention.

Comment: yes I'm using an aumented matrix, i'll be careful, I'm doing the algorithm for search 0's when a[colum][colum]==0 and swap the row for other that those not include 0's